# How to do automated functional testing of AWS components?

Tags: hadoop, automation, functional-testing, autoscaling, amazon-cloudwatch

In my project we have implemented custom auto scaling module. This module takes advantage of `AWS CloudWatch API` and uses its custom logic to auto scale up/down the cluster. All this code is in written in Java + Shell scripts. We have written unit test cases using JUnit.

Now we want to automate the functional testing but I do not know how other people do automated  functional/integration testing of AWS components and best practices for AWS component functional testing.

Consider the following scenario and expected output:

Scenario : HDFS utilization of EC2 based Hadoop cluster goes above given threshold.

Expected result : Attach new EBS volume to one of the EC2 instance in the cluster.

I would like to know which technology, language can be used to do functional testing of this scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [LocalStack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack). It provides an easy-to-use test/mocking framework for developing AWS-related applications by spinnin up the AWS-compatible APIs on your local machine or in Docker. It supports two dozen of AWS APIs and EC2 and CloudWatch are among them. It is really a great tool for functional testing without using a separate environment in AWS for that.

As for the language: you can use any language has AWS SDK. Even the AWS CLI [works with LocalStack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack#accessing-the-infrastructure-via-cli-or-code).

If you are a lucky user of Java/Kotlin and JUnit 5 I would like to recommend you to use [`aws-junit5`](https://madhead.me/posts/aws-junit5), a set of JUnit 5 extensions for AWS. And, yes, I am it's author. These extensions can be used to inject clients for AWS services provided by tools like localstack or any other AWS-compatible API (including the real AWS, of course). Both AWS Java SDK v 2.x and v 1.x are supported. You [can use `aws-junit5`](https://madhead.github.io/aws-junit5/asciidoc) to inject clients for S3, DynamoDB, Kinesis, SES, SNS and SQS.